# Stylesheets with File Dialog

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, stylesheet, traits

I'd like to incorporate a stylesheet into my Python Traits-based GUI app. Thus far I've been defining all my views in terms of QtView objects, because these allow slightly more functionality including a style_sheet property. Has there been such a modification for file dialogs and other built-in UI dialogs? From looking at traitsui.file_dialog it seems it defines everything with View rather than QtView objects. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a way that you can apply stylesheet to File-Dialog. Some default UI views may be `QDialog's`, in this case there exist a UI method, called `QFileDialog`, [documentation here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html).

So if you want to set stylesheet on the `QFileDialog` you can do this:

```
QFileDialog dialog;
dialog.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: red }");
dialog.exec_();
```

Comment: Thanks, @enginefree. I didn't realize there were so many file dialogs floating around, but I like this one a lot because it gives way more functionality than the others I've tried. It still doesn't seem to be setting the stylesheet, however. Could this be since I'm using dialog.getOpenFileName() to return the path? I tried to attach some code in this comment field but it didn't format it usefully..

Comment: More info: when I do just use dialog.show(), it appears very briefly and then disappears. If I use dialog.show() followed by dialog.getOpenFileName(), I get two dialogs, one with the stylesheet applied and another without.

Comment: Got it: to show the file dialog, the proper method is dialog.exec_()

Comment: @user2646065 Ok, Ill fix the answer.